# PHPmailer works without asking for authentication

Tags: php, email, authentication, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer() to send emails. However the mail gets sent even if I dont put in the senders address in the code. How does this work? Why the mail host does not ask for authentication? Below is the snapshot of code. I am not mentioning the mail host for security reasons.

```
        $mail->From     = '';           
        $mail->Host     = 'mailhost.domain.com';            
        $mail->Mailer   = 'smtp';
```

Comment: It is to be set in SMTP server configuration to authenticate or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to not require authentication for mail servers on your ISP's home network - they know who you are because you are on their network, so they don't need additional authentication.